# Magit configuration file location on Mac

Tags: magit

I want to reset Magit defults for particular pop up that was previously saved using `magit-popup-save-default-arguments` (https://magit.vc/manual/magit-popup.html). Where is the file created by `magit-popup-save-default-arguments` command located on Mac? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Found it: - looks like this config is saved by `transient` package and file with values could be found at `~/.emacs.d/transient/values.el`

Comment: `transient-values-file` was the variable to look.